# Шаблон проектирования "Спецификация" и его использование в .NET

Tags: c#, .net, шаблоны-проектирования, валидация

Помогите советом.

В данный момент времени есть проект, в котором находится 2 библиотеки: DAL & BLL. Слоя UI *пока* нет (в короткой перспективе будет ASP.NET Core). И есть задание с валидацией правил бизнес-логики на уровне BLL. Опять же, **читал** про FluentValidatior, но он здесь и сейчас пока не совсем уместен (ИМХО). Так вот, увидел паттерн "Спецификация" и подумал, что он неплохо может занять (заменить) нишу *static* классов-валидаторов - я планирую сделать отдельный *static* класс (без полей) для валидации той или иной модельки. Почитал статьи на [хабре про этот шаблон](https://habr.com/ru/post/325280/), на [медиум тоже есть хороший туториал](https://medium.com/c-sharp-progarmming/specification-design-pattern-c814649be0ef). Потом я задумался: на медиум [автор статьи](https://ademcatamak.medium.com/) приводит такие аргументы по использованию сего шаблона:

1."Many reasons may cause us to use this design pattern. One of these is to avoid repeating the condition rules in the code";

2."Another reason to use the specification design pattern is the situations in which the developer cannot interfere with the object";

3."Another moment of need may be that there are too many specifications of the object".

И смотрю я на свой проект и понимаю, что мои методы в классах-валидаторах вызываются в одном месте (нет дублирующих вызовов), много требований к валидации бизнес-логики у меня тоже нет.

И встал вопрос: стоит ли его все-таки реализовать - поскольку будет же слой ui, а там всего добавиться в проект. Или не торопить событие и оставить пока простые классы-валидаторы?

Спасибо.

P.S. Идея реализации валидации бизнес-логики в слое BLL закреплена в задании.